# printing multiple matches in 1 line with sed

Tags: sed

I have a `Makefile`, that has variables `version` and `build` (those are not the only variables, and can be defined in different order). Using only sed, I'd like to combine the values into a single version string.

So far I've got:

```
sed -n -e '/=/{s/version.*=\(.*\)/\1\./p;s/build.*=\(\d*\)*/\1/p}' Makefile
```

but both values are separated by newline. The above produces following output:

> ```
> 0.8.2.
> 1
> ```

I'd like:

> 0.8.2.1

I tried `N`, but couldn't figure how to use it in this sitation.

Why 'sed only' restriction? I'd like to learn it, and that is the best way for me.

Standalone sample:

```
sed -n -e '/=/ {s/version.*=\(.*\)/\1\./p;s/build.*=\(\d*\)*/\1/p}' <<EOF
foo=1
version=0.8.2
bar=2
build=1
bam=bug-AWWK
EOF
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following are all based on the same idea: store the version and build numbers, then print them at the end of input.

When it comes to storage, sed has the pattern space, which starts with the value of the current line, and a hold space, which can be used to save values for the duration of the process. The version should be wind up prepended to the value in the hold space, which can be accomplished by appending the hold space to the pattern space with `G`. The build should be appended to the hold space, which can be done with `H`. To remove the newline that `H` creates, the hold space is moved back to the pattern space. In both cases, the newline created by the `G` and `H` is removed with a `s///`, then back to the hold space with `h`. The end of input is signified by the `$` address, at which the hold space is moved back into the pattern space and printed. It's shorter to see:

```
sed -n -e '/^version.*=/ {s/[^=]*=//; G; s/\n//; h; } ' \
       -e '/^build.*=/ { s/[^=]*=//; H; g; s/\n/./; h; } ' \
       -e '$ { g; P; }'
```

This produces a newline at the end of the string, but hopefully that won't be an issue.

The awk family of utilities support variables, making the task more straightforward. They have the special variables OFS, the output field separator, and ORS, the output record separator. awk's `print` outputs the OFS between each argument, and ORS at the end. The special pattern `END` matches after the end of input.

```
awk -v OFS=. -v ORS='' \
    '/^version.*=/ {sub(/^[^=]*=/, "");  version=$0;} \
     /^build.*=/ {sub(/^[^=]*=/, ""); build=$0;} \
     END {print version, build;}'
```

If you don't care about the trailing dot and can be certain of the order of the version and build lines in the makefile:

```
awk -v ORS=. '/(version|build).*=/ { sub(/^[^=]*=/, ""); print; } '
```

Continuing upwards in expressiveness of language is perl. perl's `END` has a similar function to awk's, marking a block to be run at the end of the process. A hash can be used to store the parts of the complete version number, allowing the lines to match and store the version and build to be combined into a single line.

```
perl -n -e '$ver{$1} = $2 if /^(version|build)[^=]*=(.*)/; \
            END {$,="."; print @ver{"version","build"}};'
```

While using sed makes for an interesting exercise, the value in exercises is strengthening yourself by doing them. If you must turn to others, it's better not to focus on how you're trying to [solve the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but instead find out recommended approaches. You'll learn more.

Comment: OP mentioned "using only sed'

Comment: @Kent: What's awk, chopped liver? Sometimes there's something better than what the questioner asked for, even if it's for educational purposes. If someone asked for vice grips to remove a hex bolt when a socket wrench was close to hand, you'd hand them the socket wrench. Not that sed can't do it, it's just not quite as good. For one thing, sed will store the entire string and print it only at the end, while awk will print for each matching line. It won't make much of a difference with the example, as the output string is short, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: if I had this problem, my first try would be awk too. I feel in most case, awk is much more flexible than sed. (personal opinion). however OP do narrow the range of the answer. btw, for the awk solution from you. I didn't test. but I guess there would be extra dots (".") at the end. since for all matched line, you print \\1 and "." at the end. And the ORS and \\1"." may repeat the dot.

Comment: I see what you mean about the dots. The exact desired output wasn't clear to me at first; I thought the double dots was supposed to be another separator, distinct from single dots in the version number. Eventually, I realized what Łukasz is trying to construct: a four-part version number.

Comment: +1 for using `G;h` and `H` correctly. I submit a whittled down solution ` sed '/^version=/{s///;G;h};/^build=/{s//./;H};${g;s/\n//gp};d'`

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I learned a lot :) about problem solving, I combined sed with tr -d '\n ' and just wondered how could one do it only with sed :)

Answer (score 1):

try this with your makefile:

```
 sed -rn -e '/^(version|build)/{s#^.*=##;H;}' -e'${x;s#\n##;s#\n#\.#;p}' makefile
```

test with your example text:

```
kent$  sed -rn -e '/^(version|build)/{s#^.*=##;H;}' -e'${x;s#\n##;s#\n#\.#;p}' <<<"foo=1
dquote> version=0.8.2
dquote> bar=2
dquote> build=1
dquote> bam=bug-AWWK
dquote> EOF"
0.8.2.1
```

in case build shows before version:

```
kent$  sed -rn -e '/^(version|build)/{s#^.*=##;H;}' -e'${x;s#\n##;s#\n#\.#;p}' <<<"foo=1
bar=2
build=1
bam=bug-AWWK
version=100.8.2"
1.100.8.2
```

Comment: Can get rid of the `-r` gnu sed dependance if you use `/^version\|^build/`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cat makefile | 
sed '/^\(version\|build\)/H;${x;s/^\(\nbuild.*\)\(\n.*\)/\2\1/;s/^.*=\(.*\)\n.*=\(.*\)/\1.\2/p};d'
0.8.2.1
tac makefile | 
sed '/^\(version\|build\)/H;${x;s/^\(\nbuild.*\)\(\n.*\)/\2\1/;s/^.*=\(.*\)\n.*=\(.*\)/\1.\2/p};d'
0.8.2.1
```

If your not bothered if version comes before or after build, then:

```
sed '/^\(version\|build\)/H;${x;s/^.*=\(.*\)\n.*=\(.*\)/\1.\2/p};d'
0.8.2.1
```

Having read @outis solution, here is the ameliorated version of his solution for plainer viewing:

```
 sed '/^version=/{s///;G;h};/^build=/{s//./;H};${g;s/\n//gp};d' makefile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to `awk` then here is another solution. Prevents the finger spasms caused by typing `sed` code. *`No offence to the brilliant solutions offered by potong and kent`* ;)

```
awk -F"=" '
BEGIN{i=1}
(/version|build/){a[i]=$NF;i++}
END{for(i=1;i<=2;i++) if(i==1) {printf a[i]"."} else printf a[i]}' Makefile
```